# Owl Carousel cause blinking of youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I have a problem on this page: http://wtgecommerce.powersoftware.in/land.
The youtube video blink like something refresh it.
I opened the developer console and I noticed that this could be caused by Owl Carousel.
You can see here the code before blinking:

[image: before blinking code]

and after:

[image]

Why this is happening? And how I can fix this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to fade-in fade-out animation.

remove `transitionStyle: "fade"` or comment these line in owl.transitions.css

```
.owl-fade-out {
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut .7s both ease;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut .7s both ease;
  animation: fadeOut .7s both ease;
}
.owl-fade-in {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .7s both ease;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn .7s both ease;
  animation: fadeIn .7s both ease;
}
```